# Sql Server 2005 Bulk XML Delete?

Tags: c#, xml, sql-server-2005, sql-delete

I know you can do bulk XML inserts into SQL Server 2005 tables from your C# code using datasets/datatables.
Is it possible to do the same but as a delete?

Comment: I assume you don't want to delete everything, if not you can use truncate ...

Comment: Truncate the table. like TRUNCATE TABLE Name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove data two ways

`DELETE FROM Schema.TableName WHERE Condition = Value`

OR nuke it

`TRUNCATE TABLE Schema.TableName`

Now, if you want to Bulk Delete rows based on an XML file, you are going to have to import the data into a staging table or open it as a rowset and then do a `JOIN` or `EXISTS` to delete.